# Safari 12: how to sync tabs *only* across devices?

Tags: iphone, mac, icloud, safari

Is there a way to sync opened tabs *only* (i.e., without syncing Favorites page) in Safari across Mac and iPhone?

I have a different set of Favorite websites on iPhone and Mac — and turning sync on for Safari overwrites them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: safari preference]

You can assign another folder for Favorites (e.g iPhoneFav).

I haven't tested whether this option will be synced across devices, though.

Comment: it's a workaround, as when turning on the iCloud sync for Safari, the favorites folder will still be merged with the websites from Mac and iPhone. But choosing a different folder to display on Mac (e.g., Mac-specific favorites) will indeed show a different set of favorite tabs in Safari